# What does "not all control paths return a value" mean and how to troubleshoot. (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function for an assignment that finds the two prime numbers that add up to the given sum. The instructions ask 
*"Write a C++ program to investigate the conjecture by listing all the even numbers from 4 to 100,000 along
with two primes which add to the same number.
Br sure you program the case where you find an even number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two
primes (even though this should not occur!). An appropriate message to display would be “Conjecture
fails!” You can test this code by seeing if all integers between 4 and 100,000 can be expressed as the sum
of two primes. There should be lots of failures."*

I have created and tested the "showPrimePair" function before modifying it to integrate it into the main program, but now I run into this specific error

> "C4715    'showPrimePair': not all control paths return a value"

I have already done my research to try to fix the error but it still
 remains.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string> // new
//#include <vector> //new
//#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


bool isPrime(int n);
//bool showPrimePair(int x);
//vector <int> primes; //new
const int MAX = 100000;


//// Sieve Sundaram function // new
//
//void sieveSundaram()
//{
//  bool marked[MAX / 2 + 100] = { 0 };
//  for (int i = 1; i <= (sqrt(MAX) - 1) / 2; i++)
//      for (int j = (i * (i + 1)) << 1; j <= MAX / 2; j = j + 2 * i + 1)
//          marked[j] = true;
//
//  primes.push_back(2);
//  for (int i = 1; i <= MAX / 2; i++)
//      if (marked[i] == false)
//          primes.push_back(2 * i + 1);
//}

// Function checks if number is prime //links to showPrimePair 
bool isPrime(int n) {
    bool prime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) // condition for nonprime number
        {
            prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime;
}

// Function for showing prime pairs ( in progress)  Integer as a Sum of Two Prime Numbers
bool showPrimePair(int n) {
    bool foundPair = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i)
    // condition for i to be a prime number
    {
        if (isPrime(i) == 1)
        {
            // condition for n-i to be a prime number
            if (isPrime(n - i) == 1)
            {
                // n = primeNumber1 + primeNumber2
                printf("%d = %d + %d\n", n, i, n - i);
                foundPair = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (foundPair == false) {
        cout << " Conjecture fails!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

// Main program in listing conjectures for all even numbers from 4-100,000 along q/ 2 primes that add up to same number.

int main() 
{
    //sieveSundaram();
    cout << "Goldbach's Conjecture by Tony Pham " << endl;
    for (int x = 2; x <= MAX; x++) {
        /*if (isPrime(x) == true) { //works
            cout << x << " is a prime number " << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << x << " is not a prime number " << endl;
        }*/
        showPrimePair(x);
    }
    cout << "Enter any character to quit: ";
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: What is your specific question about the C++ programming language?

Comment: My question is how do I find the two prime numbers that make up the sum that gets displayed without user input.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, but is a general algorithm question. The logic would be the same whether the program gets written in C++, Perl, Python, Java, Javascript, Basic, or any other programming language. Stackoverflow.com is for ***specific*** technical questions related to computer programming, organized by topics, and not "how do I write X" type of generic questions. For more information, you can take a [tour] of stackoverflow, visit the [help], and learn [ask] questions here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

First you can find all prime numbers in the desired range using the *Sieve of Eratosthenes* algorithm. Next, you can insert all found primes into a hash set. Finally for each number `n` in the range you can try all primes `p` that don't exceed `n/2`, and probe if the `n-p` is also a prime (as long as you have a hash set this operation is very fast).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of Dmitry Kuzminov's answer. It takes a minute to run but it does finish within a reasonable time period. (Also, my implementation skips to the next number if a solution is found, but there are multiple solutions for each number. Finding every solution for each number simply takes WAAAAY too long.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>


std::unordered_set<long long> sieve(long long max) {
    auto arr = new long long[max];

    std::unordered_set<long long> ret;

    for (long long i = 2; i < max; i++) {
        for (long long j = i * i; j < max; j+=i) {
            *(arr + (j - 1)) = 1;
        }
    }
    for (long long i = 1; i < max; i++) {
        if (*(arr + (i - 1)) == 0)
            ret.emplace(i);
    }

    delete[] arr;

    return ret;
}

bool is_prime(long long n) {
    for(long long i = 2; i <= n / 2; ++i) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    auto primes = sieve(100000);

    for (long long n = 4; n <= 100000; n+=2) {
        bool found = false;
        for (auto prime : primes) {
            if (prime <= n / 2) {
                if (is_prime(n - prime)) {
                    std::cout << prime << " + " << n - prime << " = " << n << std::endl;
                    found = true;
                    break; // Will move onto the next number after it finds a result
                }
            }
        }

        if (!found) {  // Replace with whatever code you'd like.
            std::terminate();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Remember to use `delete[]` and clean up after ourselves.